# Is there a way to group data twice (i.e. by month and then by season) in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to answer this question:

> Use the nycflights13 package and the flights data frame to answer the following questions: What month had the highest proportion of cancelled flights? What month had the lowest? Interpret any seasonal patterns.

I've technically answered the question, but I am trying to make a more concise tibble than what I have now.

This is what I have so far:

```
#Load packages
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

#Data frame "cancprop" with three new variables ("canc" = flights that were canceled, "notc" = flights that were not canceled, and "canp" = proportion of all flights that were canceled)
cancprop <- flights %>%
  mutate(
    canc = is.na(dep_time),
    notc = !is.na(dep_time),
    canp = canc / (canc + notc)
  )

#A tibble showing the average proportion of all flights that were canceled by month sorted by descending average proportion.
cancprop %>%
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarize(mcanp = mean(canp)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(mcanp))
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   month   mcanp
   <int>   <dbl>
 1     2 0.0505 
 2    12 0.0364 
 3     6 0.0357 
 4     7 0.0319 
 5     3 0.0299 
 6     4 0.0236 
 7     5 0.0196 
 8     1 0.0193 
 9     8 0.0166 
10     9 0.0164 
11    11 0.00854
12    10 0.00817

#Data frame "seas" with a new variable ("season" = the season corresponding with the month)
seas <- cancprop %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarize(mcanp = mean(canp)) %>% 
  mutate(
    season = case_when(
      month %in% 3:5 ~ "Spring",
      month %in% 6:8 ~ "Summer",
      month %in% 9:11 ~ "Fall",
      TRUE ~ "Winter"
    ))
seas
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   month   mcanp season
   <int>   <dbl> <chr> 
 1     1 0.0193  Winter
 2     2 0.0505  Winter
 3     3 0.0299  Spring
 4     4 0.0236  Spring
 5     5 0.0196  Spring
 6     6 0.0357  Summer
 7     7 0.0319  Summer
 8     8 0.0166  Summer
 9     9 0.0164  Fall  
10    10 0.00817 Fall  
11    11 0.00854 Fall  
12    12 0.0364  Winter

#A plot showing the proportion of flights canceled
ggplot(seas, aes(x = factor(month), y = mcanp, fill = season)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Proportion of Flights Canceled", color = "Season")
```

What I am looking to create is a tibble that shows the average proportion of flights canceled per season, such as this (with random, non-calculated proportions as I am unsure how to actually get the results):

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
       season   mcanp
        <chr>   <dbl> 
 1     Winter  0.0433
 2     Spring  0.0235
 3     Summer  0.0109
 4     Fall    0.0246
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think you need `seas %>%
  group_by(season) %>%
  summarise(mcanp = mean(mcanp))` ?

Comment: That works well enough in this case, but isn't quite what I'm looking for as that takes the means of the monthly means in each season rather than taking the means of the seasons.

Comment: Using `seas %>% group_by(season) %>% summarise(mcanp = mean(mcanp))` gets 
1 Winter 0.035**4**, 2 Summer 0.028**1**, 3 Spring 0.0243, 4 Fall   0.0110
Whereas the answer I am looking for is
1 Winter 0.035**0**, 2 Summer 0.028**0**, 3 Spring 0.0243, 4 Fall   0.0110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want the proportion of cancellations, *by season*. If this is the case, you completed most of the work yourself. Do not sequentially `group_by` month and season, since your comment indicates correctly that this calculates the mean of the monthly proportions of cancellations *within each season*. Instead, create the season variable and append it to the ungrouped data frame inside a `mutate`.

```
cancprop <- flights %>%
 mutate(
  canc = is.na(dep_time),
  notc = !is.na(dep_time),
  canp = canc / (canc + notc),
  season = case_when(
     month %in% 3:5  ~ "Spring",
     month %in% 6:8  ~ "Summer",
     month %in% 9:11 ~ "Fall",
     TRUE            ~ "Winter"))

cancprop %>%
 group_by(season) %>% 
 summarize(mcanp = mean(canp)) %>% 
 arrange(desc(mcanp))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
season  mcanp
<chr>   <dbl>
1 Winter 0.0350
2 Summer 0.0280
3 Spring 0.0243
4 Fall   0.0110
```

This is the proportion of cancellations, by season, in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I needed to start from the entire data frame rather than the one grouped by months.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

cancprop <- flights %>%
  mutate(
    canc = is.na(dep_time),
    notc = !is.na(dep_time),
    canp = canc / (canc + notc),
    season = case_when(
      month %in% 3:5 ~ "Spring",
      month %in% 6:8 ~ "Summer",
      month %in% 9:11 ~ "Fall",
      TRUE ~ "Winter"
    )
  )
cancprop
# A tibble: 336,776 x 23
    year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>
 1  2013     1     1      517            515
 2  2013     1     1      533            529
 3  2013     1     1      542            540
 4  2013     1     1      544            545
 5  2013     1     1      554            600
 6  2013     1     1      554            558
 7  2013     1     1      555            600
 8  2013     1     1      557            600
 9  2013     1     1      557            600
10  2013     1     1      558            600
# ... with 336,766 more rows, and 18 more
#   variables: dep_delay <dbl>, arr_time <int>,
#   sched_arr_time <int>, arr_delay <dbl>,
#   carrier <chr>, flight <int>, tailnum <chr>,
#   origin <chr>, dest <chr>, air_time <dbl>,
#   distance <dbl>, hour <dbl>, minute <dbl>,
#   time_hour <dttm>, canc <lgl>, notc <lgl>,
#   canp <dbl>, season <chr>


mcp <- cancprop %>%
  group_by(month, season) %>% 
  summarize(mcanp = mean(canp)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(mcanp))
mcp
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   month [12]
   month season   mcanp
   <int> <chr>    <dbl>
 1     2 Winter 0.0505 
 2    12 Winter 0.0364 
 3     6 Summer 0.0357 
 4     7 Summer 0.0319 
 5     3 Spring 0.0299 
 6     4 Spring 0.0236 
 7     5 Spring 0.0196 
 8     1 Winter 0.0193 
 9     8 Summer 0.0166 
10     9 Fall   0.0164 
11    11 Fall   0.00854
12    10 Fall   0.00817

ggplot(mcp, aes(x = factor(month), y = mcanp, fill = season)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Proportion of Flights Canceled", color = "Season")
# February had the highest proportion of canceled flights and October had the lowest.


scp <- cancprop %>% 
  group_by(season) %>% 
  summarize(mcanp = mean(canp)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(mcanp))
scp
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  season  mcanp
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Winter 0.0350
2 Summer 0.0280
3 Spring 0.0243
4 Fall   0.0110

ggplot(scp, aes(x = factor(season), y = mcanp, fill = season)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Proportion of Flights Canceled", color = "Season")
# Winter had the highest proportion of canceled flights and Fall had the lowest.
```

Comment: It appears as if you figured it out yourself right as I was posting a response. Double-grouping was unnecessary to answer your question. Good job at figuring it out yourself!